# Check to see if string is an integer (includes negative numbers) PHP

Tags: php, regex, integer, isinteger

The function below checks if a string is an integer meaning it should only contain digits. But it does not check if number is negative (negative numbers should return true as well since they are integers).

```
function validateInteger($value)
{
   //need is_numeric to avoid $value = true returns true with preg_match
   return is_numeric($value) && preg_match('/^\d+$/', $value);
}
```

I ran tests and got results:

```
'12.5'      => FALSE 
12.5        => FALSE 
'a125'      => FALSE 
'125a'      => FALSE 
'1a2.5'     => FALSE 
125         => TRUE 
'abc'       => FALSE 
false       => FALSE 
true        => FALSE 
'false'     => FALSE 
'true'      => FALSE 
null        => FALSE 
'null'      => FALSE 
'1231'      => TRUE 
-1231       => FALSE (SHOULD RETURN TRUE)
'-1231'     => FALSE (SHOULD RETURN TRUE)
```

I dont want to use `itnval() < 0`. I would prefer regular expression to check for negative numbers as well.

Thanks

EDIT:

I also have a function `validateFloat` that returns true if a given number is floating number meaning it can contain only **digits** and **a dot**. I need to apply same logic to this as well so that it returns true for **negative floating numbers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `is_numeric(abs($val))`

Comment: @GGio well then `is_numeric($val) && is_numeric(abs($val))`

Comment: My DownVote: `is_numeric( abs( '125a' ) )` leads to a false positive.

Answer (score 4):

[`is_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) isn't good enough for you?

`filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` should have the same effect but also work on strings.

Comment: but that returns false if value is a string but contains all digits. In my case '125' and '-1231' would return false

Comment: filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) returns true if the $input = true. it should be false in that case

Comment: @GGio Try adding the option `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`

Comment: @GGio actually it seems like it will get cast to an `int`, so I think you just need to do an explicit check `$input !== true && filter_var(...`

Comment: `filter_var( '-010', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT )` leads to a false negative, while `(int)'-010'` returns `-10`.